# Code worked six hours ago. Code was not touched for six hours. Now code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, leap-motion

We're working on a JavaScript project with the Leap Motion controller. The code was working fine this morning, but, six hours later, it is now dysfunctional, erratic, and unresponsive. We put in alerts to see up until when it stops running, and it stops running when it reaches Leap.loop; we think the problem is something somewhere is becoming overloaded, but we don't know programming enough to actually have a grasp of what's wrong. We've tried it on different hardware (different servers and different local drives), and the only response we're getting is the "Some webpages are unresponsive. Kill or Ignore?" popup.

```
<title>THIS SUCKS</title>
<style>
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #024;
  color: #fff;
}
#wrap {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.half {
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  float: left;
}
div {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#hands,
#fingers {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 200px;
}
</style>
<script src="//js.leapmotion.com/0.2.0-beta1/leap.min.js"></script>
  <div id="gestureData"></div>
<script>
// Store frame for motion functions
var previousFrame = null;

// Setup Leap loop with frame callback function
var controllerOptions = {enableGestures: true};

var url = "";

try {
     request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } catch (trymicrosoft) {
     try {
       request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
     } catch (othermicrosoft) {
       try {
         request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       } catch (failed) {
         request = false;
       }  
     }
   }

Leap.loop(controllerOptions, function(frame) {

  // Display Gesture object data
  var gestureOutput = document.getElementById("gestureData");
  var gestureString = "";
  if (frame.gestures.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < frame.gestures.length; i++) {
      var gesture = frame.gestures[i];

      switch (gesture.type) {
        case "circle":
              gestureString += "<br>ID: " + gesture.id + "<br>type: " + gesture.type + ", "
                        + "<br>center: " + vectorToString(gesture.center) + " mm, "
                        + "<br>normal: " + vectorToString(gesture.normal, 2) + ", "
                        + "<br>radius: " + gesture.radius.toFixed(1) + " mm, "
                        + "<br>progress: " + gesture.progress.toFixed(2) + " rotations"
                        + "<br>";

              url = "http://192.168.130.234:5050/layerApi.aspx?cmd=move&move=Play";

            break;
        case "swipe":
          //Classify swipe as either horizontal or vertical
          var isHorizontal = Math.abs(gesture.direction[0]) > Math.abs(gesture.direction[1]);
          //Classify as right-left or up-down
          if(isHorizontal){
            if (Math.abs(gesture.direction[0]) > Math.abs(gesture.direction[2])){
              if(gesture.direction[0] > 0){
                  swipeDirection = "Right";
              } else {
                  swipeDirection = "Left";
              }
            } else {
              if(Math.abs(gesture.direction[2].toFixed(2)) > 0.5){
                    swipeDirection = "Play";
              }
            }
          } else { //vertical
            if (Math.abs(gesture.direction[1]) > Math.abs(gesture.direction[2])){
              if(gesture.direction[1] > 0){
                  swipeDirection = "Up";
              } else {
                  swipeDirection = "Down";
              }
            } else {
              if(Math.abs(gesture.direction[2].toFixed(2)) > 0.5){
                    swipeDirection = "Play";
              }
            }
          }

          url = "http://192.168.130.234:5050/layerApi.aspx?cmd=move&move=" + swipeDirection;

          gestureString += "<br>ID: " + gesture.id + "<br>type: " + gesture.type + ", "
                        + "<br>direction " + swipeDirection
                        + "<br>url " + url
                        + "<br>gesture.direction vector: " + vectorToString(gesture.direction, 2) + ", "
                        + "<br>";
          break;
       }
     }
  }
  gestureOutput.innerHTML = gestureString + gestureOutput.innerHTML;

  PlayShow();
})

var notStarted = true;

function vectorToString(vector, digits) {
  if (typeof digits === "undefined") {
    digits = 1;
  }
  return "(" + vector[0].toFixed(digits) + ", "
             + vector[1].toFixed(digits) + ", "
             + vector[2].toFixed(digits) + ")";
}

function PlayShow () {
  var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  //The "false" puts XMLHttpRequest in synchronous mode, and the code following will wait for a response before executing.
   xhReq.open("GET", url, false); //(If these are really on the same domain, you might need to make this a relative call rather than an absolute one for it to work, not sure)
   xhReq.send(null);
  //put the response into reqResult
   var reqResult = xhReq.responseText;

  //check that the call was successful
  if (reqResult=="<Status>Success</Status>") {  //may want to change to a "contains" compare rather than an "equals"
  showRunning = true;
  } 
  else {
  showRunning = false;
  }
  // result is now in reqResult
  if (showRunning){
  showText.innerHTML="Running Show";
  } else
  showText.innerHTML="Error! Try Again?";
  notStarted=true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: It is likely your script is not being loaded correctly. Try removing the double `//` in front of `<script src="//js.leapmotion.com/0.2.0-beta1/leap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: that shouldn't matter, but can easily be verified in the developers tab.  Having `//` just means the file will load over whatever protocol the site is being served on (http or https)

Comment: I visited their website and they're currently linking version 0.4.1 (js.leapmotion.com/leap-0.4.1.min.js). This might (partly) be happening because you're using an outdated version.

Comment: Updating that didn't make a difference; it ran fine this morning even with the older version.

Comment: Using synchronous `XHR` requests is silly.  Why not just take advantage of callbacks?  That could certainly cause a page to be less responsive while it waits for a response.

Comment: witchery! or you need VCS

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing with the URL: 192.168.130.234, but when you say you tried it on different servers and hardware, did you change the URL to match? Even on the same machine 6 hours later, the IP address could change.